# Why is copy constructor needed to declare and initialize an object in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

For my question, I need you to consider this struct:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() { /* hooray, this is default ctor! */ }

private:
    Foo(const Foo&);
};
```

When I want to instantiate it like this:

```
Foo foo = Foo();
```

The compiler complains about `Foo`'s copy constructor being inaccessible (or deleted for C++11). Why would it need a copy constructor to initialize my object?

Anyway, I *turned this copy constructor public* expecting it would be called... But guess what? It is not!

So, here is my question: why would the compiler need a copy constructor it actually does not use to instantiate my object?

**N.B.**: I noticed this behavior when I wrote `auto foo = Foo();`

**EDIT**:

- g++ 4.8: deleting the copy ctor will produce a compile error
- msvc (vc100, vc120): does not complain if the copy ctor is deleted
- in any case: making the copy ctor private will produce a compile error

Comment: when you assign the copy constructor is required.

Comment: @faisal - this is **not** assignment; it's initialization. This **form** of initialization requires a copy constructor.

Answer (score 5):

This is a copy-initialization

```
Foo foo = Foo();
```

Semantically, it means a `Foo` is default constructed on the RHS, and the LHS is copy-constructed from it. Therefore there must be an accessible copy constructor.

In practice, [the copy can be *elided*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), so only one default construction takes place. This is why the copy constructor is not called.

Note that implementations are allowed, but not mandated, to perform copy elision under certain circumstances. Enforcing that the copy constructor be accessible ensures that the code compiles on all platforms, regardless of whether they perform the elision or not.